# What is the meaning or usage of the に at the end of the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation, usage, particles

> あなたもできる対処法とは? 不安から日常安心できる生活**に** 。

So what does the に here refer to? Is it になる?

Comment: What is the context? An ad of a drug, a title of a blog, or something else?